# equations overrun tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

The following works, but the equation spills over outside the box, is there a way to make the box bigger?

***Edit:***
After making the MWE I realize that this is clearly a margins issue, so I'm not sure the original question is valid...

***MWE:***

Compile the following with `pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
% formatting
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


% figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figs/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% tables
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

% date
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}

% set the styling for python code
\setminted[python]{frame=lines,framesep=2mm,bgcolor=black!10,fontsize=\footnotesize,linenos}

\begin{document}

\section*{new}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ex tation diceret suscipit, et quo quidam sententiae. Ut nam accusam persequeris, in cum harum ridens prodesset. Ut has melius voluptua principes, ne altera suscipiantur eum, vis autem simul omnes te. Alia posse abhorreant id mea, has vide iusto argumentum te, per pertinax erroribus ad. Probo definiebas referrentur has in. Enim adolescens ne nam, alii dissentiet ad qui, eam id dico moderatius.
Nihil persius repudiandae has at, an aliquid apeirian concludaturque sed. An facer ancillae mei. Eam ridens euripidis ex, ius ignota perpetua vulputate in. Vel an cibo quaestio, saepe tempor oportere ea sea, eu sea elit fabulas quaestio. Per solet tantas no.
Pri brute reprehendunt id, id soleat senserit repudiandae eum. Cu eum utroque molestiae. Purto illum malis ad pro. Saepe noluisse elaboraret eu sit. An vel verear antiopam, sale scriptorem suscipiantur ex has, est utamur accusamus signiferumque id. Postea efficiendi appellantur an usu, facer dignissim ius id.
Nec ridens delicata an, agam dissentias temporibus te nec, usu autem aperiam et. Mutat neglegentur vim eu. Ei ius mazim liber dissentiunt, an mea partem viderer moderatius, vim tantas nullam postea eu. An sint graeco disputando pro, possim aliquam definitiones et has.
Justo volutpat nam et. Eam ne elitr dolorem iracundia, id vero erroribus intellegat eum. Tacimates philosophia ad mei, sit nihil possit molestie ne, duo prima recusabo an. Veri impetus in est.
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=black]
  \textit{blah.}
  \tcblower
  \begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial J_j}{\partial \theta_i} J_j(\theta_i) &= 
              -\frac{y^{j}}{\sigma(x^{(j)}\theta^T)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i}\sigma(z)
              -\frac{1-y^{j}}{1-\sigma(x^{(j)}\theta^T)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i}1-\sigma(z)
              \text{\hspace{2em}comment comment comment}\\[0.5em]
  \end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

***MWE Output:***
[image]

Comment: Please, can you put a complete code? This it is important also for the package that you have used.

Comment: If equations are exceed the text width or box width, you have to break it per standard procedure else use `breqn.sty` for auto break

Comment: Please be more precise about the expected output. The box should already be exactly as wide as the textwidth. You have three options: i) split the equation into multiple lines to make it narrower or ii) decrease the margins or iii) make the box wider and let it overflow into the margins. Another guess: Do you use a `twocolumn` documentclass and do you want the box to occupy both columns instead on just one? Please clarify.

Comment: thanks for all the helpful comments.  I have updated with MWE as @Sebastiano suggested.  with this output it is clearly a margins issue so I can search the relevant posts for margins adjustment or just make it multiline

Comment: Try `\tag*{comment comment comment}` in place of `\text{\hspace{2em}comment comment comment}`.

Comment: thanks @muzimuzhiZ that's perfect.  thanks for the previous users who suggested an mwe, which showed that it was overrun of the comment, not the equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, displayed equations cannot auto break. Packages [`breqn`](https://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) and [`nath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/nath)
both introduce some sort of auto breaking and alignment for displayed equations.

In your case, perhaps using `\tag*{comment comment comment}` in place of `\text{\hspace{2em}comment comment comment}` is enough.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
% formatting
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


% figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figs/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% tables
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

% date
%\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}

% set the styling for python code
\setminted[python]{frame=lines,framesep=2mm,bgcolor=black!10,fontsize=\footnotesize,linenos}

\begin{document}

\section*{new}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ex tation diceret suscipit, et quo quidam sententiae. Ut nam accusam persequeris, in cum harum ridens prodesset. Ut has melius voluptua principes, ne altera suscipiantur eum, vis autem simul omnes te. Alia posse abhorreant id mea, has vide iusto argumentum te, per pertinax erroribus ad. Probo definiebas referrentur has in. Enim adolescens ne nam, alii dissentiet ad qui, eam id dico moderatius.
Nihil persius repudiandae has at, an aliquid apeirian concludaturque sed. An facer ancillae mei. Eam ridens euripidis ex, ius ignota perpetua vulputate in. Vel an cibo quaestio, saepe tempor oportere ea sea, eu sea elit fabulas quaestio. Per solet tantas no.
Pri brute reprehendunt id, id soleat senserit repudiandae eum. Cu eum utroque molestiae. Purto illum malis ad pro. Saepe noluisse elaboraret eu sit. An vel verear antiopam, sale scriptorem suscipiantur ex has, est utamur accusamus signiferumque id. Postea efficiendi appellantur an usu, facer dignissim ius id.
Nec ridens delicata an, agam dissentias temporibus te nec, usu autem aperiam et. Mutat neglegentur vim eu. Ei ius mazim liber dissentiunt, an mea partem viderer moderatius, vim tantas nullam postea eu. An sint graeco disputando pro, possim aliquam definitiones et has.
Justo volutpat nam et. Eam ne elitr dolorem iracundia, id vero erroribus intellegat eum. Tacimates philosophia ad mei, sit nihil possit molestie ne, duo prima recusabo an. Veri impetus in est.
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=black]
  \textit{blah.}
  \tcblower
  \begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial J_j}{\partial \theta_i} J_j(\theta_i) &= 
              -\frac{y^{j}}{\sigma(x^{(j)}\theta^T)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i}\sigma(z)
              -\frac{1-y^{j}}{1-\sigma(x^{(j)}\theta^T)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i}1-\sigma(z)
              \tag*{comment comment comment}
  \end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]